# Why there is no $5$-dimensional analogous of Quaternions?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, quaternions

Why there is no $5$-dimensional analogous of Quaternions? Why the following definition is not well-defined?
$$i^2=j^2=k^2=\ell^2=ijk=jk\ell=k\ell i=-1,\quad ijkl=1.$$

Comment: $ijk=-1$ and $ijkl=1$ implies $-1(l)=1$

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are looking for a real vector space $V$ with basis $\{1,i,j,k,\ell\}$ and an associative product such that $V$ becomes an $\Bbb{R}$-algebra, then we run into the following difficulty.

The rule that $i^2=-1$ means that $V$ also has a structure as a vector space over the field $\Bbb{C}=\Bbb{R}(i)$.

But a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$ necessarily has an even dimension as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$.

---

The above is probably not the shortest route to a contradiction (see the comment by verret). But it also rules out many modifications to the suggested relations defining the product.

Comment: In the same vein, if $\Bbb{H}$ is the usual division algebra of quaternions then any associative algebra $A$ containing $\Bbb{H}$ as a subalgebra is also a free left (or right) $\Bbb{H}$-module. Therefore $\dim_{\Bbb{R}}A$ is necessarily divisible by four.

Comment: I think we can actually relax associativity a bit, but I'm not sure about the best way of phrasing that :-)

Comment: Slightly more relaxed: if $A$ is a real alternative algebra with $n$ anticommuting square roots of negative one, then $A$ is a representation of the Clifford algebra ${\rm Cliff}(n)$. Since $\mathrm{Cliff}(n)\cong M_k(\Bbb K)$ for some $k$, the dimensions of its reps are all multiples of $km$ where $m=1,2,2,4,4,8$ and $\Bbb K=\Bbb R,\Bbb R^2,\Bbb C,\Bbb C^2,\Bbb H,\Bbb H^2$. Note $k$ and $\Bbb K$ can be determined from $n$ using the "Clifford clock."

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: (After 3 years) Your argument says that its dim is even. So what we can say in dim 6 similar to your argument?

Comment: @C.F.G Dimension six is likely more difficult to deal with. There are arguments proving that 6-dimensional division algebras over $\Bbb{R}$ don't exist, but they are more complicated. If we relax on the division algebra requirement, then the algebra may or may not exist, all depending what properties we want it to have.